# Are these claims about Puri Jagannath Temple really true?

Tags: belief, temple, jagan-natha

Now I am interested to visit Lord Jagannath temple in Puri after reading 
 following facts about it [(source)](https://www.speakingtree.in/blog/eight-miracles-at-puri-jagannath-temple/m-lite). Are these claims true?

> 1. The flag always flaps in a direction opposite to the direction in which the wind is blowing.
> 2. Gaze from any place in Puri, and you will always find the Sudarshan Charka (charka at the top of the temple) always facing you.
> 3. Normally during day-time, the wind blows from the sea to the land and in the evening, the opposite happens. But in Puri, the opposite happens.
> 4. Birds or planes do not fly above the temple.
> 5. The shadow of the main dome is invisible at any time of day.
> 6. The quantity of cooked food inside the temple remains same the entire year. And the same prasadam can feed whatever be the number of devotees - a few thousand people or 20 lakh people. It never gets wasted.
> 7. In the temple kitchen, seven pots are kept on top of each other and cooked on firewood. In this process, the contents in the top pot get cooked first, lastly, the bottommost one!
> 8. On entering from Singhadwara, as one takes the first step inside the Temple, you can’t hear any sound produced by the ocean. But when you cross the same step outside the Temple, you can hear it.

Comment: I presume you are an Oriya living in Orissa. Then how come you have never visited the Jagannatha Temple?

Comment: Yes, I never visited there. I stay at Mumbai

Comment: Okay i mistakenly thought that you live in Orissa only.

Comment: You are right, I am from Odisha but staying and working at Mumbai from long time and come to my village rarely so I could not get a chance to visit Puri Jagannath temple

Comment: Some people says "jiska Dori/nasib khulta he wohi darshan kar Sakta he Jagannath Mandir"

Comment: It would be better if you go there and watch it yourself. coz to ans this question one has to verify above mention facts.

Comment: I heard from others that 1,3 and 5 are true rest I don't know.. ( I never visited.)

Comment: voting to close as 'scientific speculation'

Answer (score 5):

- 2) False

  [image: enter link description here]
- 4) Birds no; but [planes WILL fly](https://www.telegraphindia.com/1140717/jsp/odisha/story_18621718.jsp)

  > Bhubaneswar, July 16: The director-general of civil aviation has turned down a proposal to make no-flying zone over the Sri Jagannath Temple in Puri.
  >
  > “The ministry of civil aviation has taken a policy decision that no-flying zones are not to be created as they affect the safety and efficiency of flight operations,”
- 5) The shadow of the main dome always falls on the building itself and that's why invisible at any time

  > [image]
- 7) True, I've seen it
- 8) true

Comment: I suggest to add some explanation and reference to the answer. Visit [answer].

Comment: @Pandya The question is asking whether they are true or not. Answer explained it. What explanation do you expect?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma The question itself doesn't make sense, it amounts to scientific verification of a belief. No wonder you'll see such answers.

Comment: The question asked about the environment of a Hindu temple, I answered with links. There is NO "scientific verification" involved. 

Anyway, what do you want explained ?

Comment: Ok. I tried to improve somewhat to look the answer better /cc @Sarvabhouma

Comment: @Pandya How does the first picture you inserted disprove the claim? What is the reference point for wind direction? How do you know which way the wind is blowing? My advice is to move the post to Skeptics.SE to get better answers.

Comment: 2nd claim says: "Gaze from any place in Puri, and you will always find the Sudarshan Charka (Charka at the top of the temple) always facing you." From the picture, you can see the Chakra is NOT facing the photographer.